# ssh for single user over vpn no prompt

Tags: ssh, vpn, connection

this is a very strange issue to me.

from a ubuntu 18.04 machine on a VPN client can successfully ssh for multiple users (e.g. ssh user1@server, ssh user2@server) works fine. But there is one user that instead of getting a prompt after ssh'ing into the server get's a blank line. and only ctrl-d will escape.

this user account can successfully ssh into the server from onsite PCs as well as from other vpn clients.

What should I be looking for? the logs on the ssh server give no error. This is what they say for the user with debug3.

```
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43180]: Starting session: shell on pts/20 for USER from USER_IP port 43776 id 0
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43180]: debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43180]: debug3: fd 12 is O_NONBLOCK
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43180]: debug3: send packet: type 99
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43181]: debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43181]: debug3: Copy environment: XDG_SESSION_ID=19429
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43181]: debug3: Copy environment: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000003
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43181]: debug3: Copy environment: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43181]: debug3: Copy environment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43180]: debug2: fd 14 setting O_NONBLOCK
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43180]: debug2: channel 0: rfd 14 isatty
Nov 25 14:58:21 SERVER sshd[43180]: debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
```

Comment: What's `userx`'s shell? From `user1`, `getent passwd userx`. Check `~userx/` shell startup files. `.profile`, `.bashrc` or whatever (read the `man` page for the `userx` shell). Something in there is doing an no prompt `read` from `STDIN`. When you `^D` (EOF), whatever did the `read` exits with FAILURE, which aborts the login.

Comment: shells are `bash` for all users. the user with the error does have `.bash_profile` and `.login` files. `.bash_profile` is a color support script. and `.login` is a few `export var` commands. 
the `.bash_profile` is [lines 37-85 from here](https://gist.github.com/awesomebytes/c5885775ac9b7429cfcf7cb99b14f3cf).
With line 40 being edited to this, `    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;`
i don't see a call to `STDIN` or `read` in these files.

Comment: This will help: `cd ~userx; HOME="$(pwd)" bash -ix ./.bash_profile` as a non-root user.

Comment: thanks for your help. I was not working over the break.
Update: I was able to login as that user from that computer. I did `ctrl+c` upon seeing the blank line and voila i received a prompt. all seems to be working now. I am pretty confused as to what was happening. Is it possible there was a background script that was running for a long time that prohibited completion of all login scripts? ...Anyway, i ran `bash -ix ./.bash_profile` as userx (so didn't need the cd, or HOME commands). i got a lot of unexpected output. e.g.
`+ '[' -z '\s-\v\$ ' ']'
+ shopt -s checkwinsize
+ '[' -z '' ']'`